# Can't connect c# to mongoDb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, robo3t

I'm trying to connect to a program coded in C# to a mongoDB.
I have created a new collection and I have inserted some data . I'm using mlab as host for my dataBase.

```
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("ds145128.mlab.com", 45128);
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);

var db = client.GetDatabase("unknowndb");
var coll = db.GetCollection<Book>("book");
```

Please help me, when I execute the program, it show me a error message that I can't connect to the DB?

Comment: It looks like you are not passing login credentials to `MongoClient`

Comment: What error message are you getting from that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I connected like that

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CONNECTION_STRING_NAME].ConnectionString;
var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
var client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl);
var database = client.GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
```

And my connection string like this. I connected to local mongodb. You can use MongoUrl

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][/[database][?options]]

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/dbtest?readPreference=primary
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for you answers, this is how to connect with mongodb c# driver 2.0.1

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = MainAsync(args);
        t.Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("name");
        var coll = db.GetCollection<Book>("collName");}
```